# Run pre validation builds if PR's are raised by a specific Team in VSTS/Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-devops-rest-api

Problem Statement: I have a shared repository shared between 3 teams. They have some shared components and some individual components. We have a mainline branch A wherein all 3 teams merge their feature branches.
Presently there are no build policies, hence we get a huge list of sales force validation errors. This delays our planned deployments.

Tried out solution: We created a clone sales force org and pipeline. Enforced branch policy such that it would run a build on the clone org each time a PR was raised in branch A. However the issue with this is all PR's from the 3 teams got validated on my personal org.

Since we have our team members in a particular group in VSTS, I wanted to know if we can force this policy for specific team/group in VSTS. The idea is to run validation builds on my personal org for only the PR's that are raised by my team.

Comment: you can filter the build validation with path filters. I don't think you can with team/group filter.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the different teams should be responsible for their corresponding components. Thus, you could add `Path filter` in the build policy to only include your team components.

> If a path filter is set, the policy will only apply when files which
> match the filter are changes. Leaving this field blank means that the
> policy will always apply.
>
> You can specify absolute paths and wildcards.
>
> Example: /WebApp/Models/Data.cs, /WebApp/*, or *.cs
>
> You can specify multiple paths using ";" as a separator.
>
> Example: /WebApp/Models/Data.cs;ClientApp/Models/Data.cs
>
> Paths prefixed with "!" are excluded.
>
> Example: /WebApp/*;!/WebApp/Tests/*
>
> Order is significant.

[image]

Comment: I did try out this option, but we have more than 10000 components and have a common folder structure. Objects will contain all object files from 3 teams. CSS will contain all CSS files from the team.

Comment: Since there is no team/group filter, if path filter doesn't work for you, you may consider creating a new branch from branch A, and validate in this new branch. Branches are lightweight in Git, you can dispose of the branch later.

Comment: We have been doing the branch based setup, however it is too much of a manual intervention and is not really helpful from a CI standpoint. However, I plan to keep this question open for a few more days and see if the any of the community members have any idea. Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Let's wait and see whether we can get more ideas.:-)